# GPS module Ublox Neo 6M issue

Tags: arduino-uno, gps

I using the above mentioned GPS module with Arduino UNO. I find that I cannot receive the Latitude and Longitude values in the `$GPRMC` string in the NMEA data, as I used the module inside a concrete building. I got the values when I placed the module just outside the window. But I have noticed that the phones we use can get the location data just fine through their in-built GPS after waiting for just some time. How is this possible? Any way I can achieve this using the Ublox Neo 6M module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mobile phones use the mechanism of [assisted GPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assisted_GPS?wprov=sfla1).

In contrast to your Arduino U-Blox module it uses the cell tower data your phone can provide to determine your location. This is especially helpful to get a quicker first fix and to get a fix even when you have poor satellite signal conditions.

That said, this will not be possible using only your GPS module connected to your Arduino.